# Adding Controls on the Client-Side and getting data from them on the server side in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net

Is there any method/framework/component in **ASP.NET** to allow easily adding/removing the controls to the page in the client-side and then collecting their data in postback?

Comment: I think this probably belongs on StackOverflow.com

Answer (score 0):

You can't add controls to the page client side.

What you can do is to add html elements, and handle them separately in the code behind. You use the `Request.Form` collection to read the data posted to the server. (The collection also contains the data posted by the elements rendered by the controls, that's where the controls read their data.)